# freeswitch - group dialing, registration issue

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to setup a group dial for a given extension.

The bridge command I pass data specifying two call groups.

group/support|group/sales

Inside the directory I have users assigned to these call groups, some of which which are configured using only cellphone numbers by overriding the dial string parameter (no sip device).

However, when I try to call, the given user is not dialed as they are not registered (Originate Failed.  Cause USER_NOT_REGISTERED. )   How can I configure a given user xml so that freeswitch will not skip over it for not being registered?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

you can define `dial-string` in the user entry in the directory so that it dials the user's external number. In this example, I used loopback endpoint, and you can also define a string with the sofia gateway:

```
<param name="dial-string" value="[group_confirm_key=1,leg_delay_start=15]loopback/0794070224/${context}"/>
```

`group_confirm_key` defines that the user has to press 1 to accept the call -- this way you can be sure that the call does not land in voicemail.

`leg_delay_start=15` is done because I have a SIP desktop phone, and I let it ring for the first 15 seconds.